How to test components dependent on utils/functions?
Im new to testing in React using vitest. Im trying to test component that not only displays data but also manipulate them using some type of util.
This is very simple example with ReservationCard that displays reservation label and then formated date using function from util.
    import { formatDate } from "./utils"
    
     interface ReservationCardProps {
      reservation: Reservation;
      showDetailDialog: () => void;
    }
    
    const ReservationCard: FC<ReservationCardProps> = ({reservation, showDetailDialog}) => {
    return (
      <div>
      <h2>{reservation.label}</h2>
      <p>{formatDate(reservation.startDate)}</p>
      <button onClick={showDetailDialog}>Open detail</button>
      </div>
    )

What I know:
I would test if passing the reservation object would display the label. But how should I test the util function so I can check if the given date gets formated. Also should I test the user action for displaying the detail dialog? And if yes, should I only just check in the test that the dialog gets rendered or also its content?
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import ReservationCard from "./ReservationCard";
import DetailDialog from "./dialogs/DetailDialog"

describe("ReservationCard", () => {
  it("Renders correctly reservation card", () => {

const reservation = {
  label: "My reservation",
  startDate: "2024-12-24"
}

    render(<ReservationCard reservation={reservation} showDetailDialog={show(DetailDialog)}  />);
    expect(screen.getByText(reservation.label)).toBeVisible();
  });
 //?? How to test the util if the date is present and formated. Also how to test the dialog if it opens on click and what to check in the dialog if even anything.
});


My idea is you should write separate test cases(files) for utils and DetailDialog since they are separated from ReservationCard. When you write test case in ReservationCard, there is three things that need to be assert.

does the label display
does the date display (Here we only check if it is display, we should write separate test cases for utils)
does the button click trigger properly

So here is how I do it
const mockedShowDetailDialog = vi.fn();

test('should render ReservationCard', async () => {
  render(
    <ReservationCard
      reservation={{ label: 'Hello', startDate: '7/23/2024' }}
      showDetailDialog={mockedShowDetailDialog}
    />
  );

  // assert label text
  expect(screen.getByTestId('reservation-label')).toHaveTextContent('Hello');

  // assert date
  expect(screen.getByTestId('reservation-date')).toHaveTextContent('7/23/2024');

  // click the button
  await userEvent.setup().click(screen.getByTestId('details-button'));

  // assert button click event
  expect(mockedShowDetailDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

Here I added a few data test ids in ReservationCard component and I created very simple util function for formatDate. actually it returns the same value we passed 

I see that you have used getByTestId instead of getByText, is it better approche to find the element using its test id?
Also should I use it("description here", () => for each of the part of the test? to separet checking abel, date and the button click?

Yes, using getByTestId is useful if we have multiple elements with the same content(ex-: same text content) or if the text is dynamic. We can use describe blocks to organize test cases if there are too many.
